# Xcode: Make A Text Field Bring Up A Picker View or Drop Down Menu

Tags: xcode4, ios5, uitextview, uipickerview, drop-down-menu

Can someone please provide some example code on how I could create the following features on an iOS app:

**Option 1:**
I want to create a text field through Interface Builder, and when someone clicks on that text field, instead of bringing up the default keyboard, I want it to bring up a Picker View which lists several choices of my liking. Once the user is done picking a certain value, they can click on a "done" button by the picker view and the picker view will go away and the Text Field will be populated with what they chose on the Picker View.

**Option 2**
If the previous method will require too much code to accomplish, could someone provide example code on how to create a basic Drop Down menu similar to how a standard drop down menu on a website?

Thanks

Comment: "and the Text Field will not be populated with what they chose on the Picker View." Er... don't you mean the text field **will** be populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file.  I called mine AEMPicker.  The .h:

```
@protocol AEMPickerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)touchedPicker:(NSString *)string;

@optional
-(void)setInitialPickerValueToRow:(int)i inComponent:(int)j animated:(BOOL)k;

@end

@interface AEMPicker : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>{
    UIPickerView *pickerView;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *contentArray;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<AEMPickerDelegate> delegatePicker;

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)contents inFrame:(CGRect)pickerFrame;
@end
```

the .m:

```
#import "AEMPicker.h"

@implementation AEMPicker

@synthesize contentArray;
@synthesize delegatePicker;

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)contents inFrame:(CGRect)pickerFrame
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: contents];

        pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        pickerView.delegate = self;

        [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setInitialPickerValueToRow:(int)i inComponent:(int)j animated:(BOOL)k{
    [pickerView selectRow:i inComponent:j animated:k];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {    
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [contentArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [contentArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [self.delegatePicker touchedPicker:[contentArray objectAtIndex:row]];
}

@end
```

Now, in the class you want to present your pickerView, after `#import AEMPicker;` add to your .h:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <AEMPickerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>{
AEMPicker *picker;
UIPopoverController *pickerPopOver;
UIPopoverController *pOC;
CGRect popRect;
}
```

add to your .m:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    popRect = CGRectMake(406, 110, 0, 0);
    CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0, 10, 0, 0);

    NSArray *contents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Object 1", @"Object 2", @"Object 3", nil];
    picker = [[AEMPicker alloc] initWithArray:contents inFrame:pickerRect];
    picker.delegatePicker = self;

    pickerPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    pickerPopOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 250);
    [pickerPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:TRUE];

        pOC = pickerPopOver;
}

-(void)touchedPicker:(NSString *)string{

    [yourTextField setText:string];
    [pickerPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    [pOC dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

That should give you a pretty basic picker popover to play with.

Comment: Xcode is calling a "use of undeclared identifier" on popRect, however I know do not know what popRect is supposed to be in this so would you mind adding a declaration of popRect, or explaining why this error is occurring?

Comment: Sorry-- add `CGRect popRect;` to the .h file of the class that implements the picker.  I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you very much everything seems to be working now, however my picker does not seem to show the blue highlighted selector over the currently selected value in the picker, although the value in the center is still being selected. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Actually, no, I don't.  Shows up fine on my implementation.

Comment: This is so weird and frustrating... Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: Make sure you include `pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;`

Comment: The picker view works, but there comes a message : -[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: the rect passed in to this method must have non-zero width and height. This will be an exception in a future release.
I have changed e.g. => popRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 120); and the error message is now away.
I use: Xcode 4.6 & iOS SDK 6.1

Comment: Yeah, the idea was to give a basic implementation that users could play around with.  To that effect, presizing the picker would have been counter-productive.  Please upvote if you use the code, and share if you can.