# UIPickerController - want to show specific selection upon loading

Tags: xcode, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I have a custom UIPickerView that is embedded into an UIActionsheet that comes up half the screen when called.  Works great.  The problem is that I want to have the barrelPicker be showing the 'most probable' results as the selection when it first comes up (after all the data has been loaded into it).
Prior to having the custom picker embedded in the action sheet, I had it in a UIViewController and was just calling "showProbableResults" (a custom method of mine) in the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController, because I knew at that point, the UIPickerView would be loaded up and ready to go.  Is there an equivalent place for me to call this method now or do I need to rethink my whole design?  Essentially, what I need is a place to call this after the UIPickerView has been loaded.

```
    - (void)startWithDelegate:(UIViewController <ImageProcessingDelegate> *)sender

{
self.delegate = sender;
self.showFirstBottle = YES;
[self start];
```

}

```
- (void) start {

self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Something"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];

[self.actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

NSLog(@"1.) About to alloc the picker");

self.vintagePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
self.vintagePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.vintagePicker.dataSource = self;
self.vintagePicker.delegate = self;

[self.actionSheet addSubview:self.vintagePicker];
[self.vintagePicker release];

UISegmentedControl *nextButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Next"]];
nextButton.momentary = YES; 
nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
nextButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
nextButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(show:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.actionSheet addSubview:nextButton];
[nextButton release];

UISegmentedControl *backButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Back"]];
backButton.momentary = YES; 
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
backButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
backButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.actionSheet addSubview:backButton];
[backButton release];

[self.actionSheet showInView:_delegate.parentViewController.tabBarController.view]; // show from our table view (pops up in the middle of the table)
[self.actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
```

}

Comment: Is your action sheet/picker a custom class?  Please give us some code.

Comment: Yes my action sheet and picker is a custom class of NSObject <UIActionSheetDelegate> - the code above is what kicks it off.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a reusable picker view, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744133/542400), and then call the @optional

```
-(void)setInitialPickerValueToRow:(int)i inComponent:(int)j animated:(BOOL)k{
    [pickerView selectRow:i inComponent:j animated:k];
}
```

from any view controller or NSObject (such as your UIActionSheetDelegate).

Your other option is to set a standard pre-chosen selection, as follows:

```
self.vintagePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
self.vintagePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
self.vintagePicker.dataSource = self;
self.vintagePicker.delegate = self;
[self.actionSheet addSubview:self.vintagePicker];
[self.vintagePicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

You could also have different variables that you set, and have `selectRow:inComponent:animated:` access those, instead of being preset.

```
[self.vintagePicker selectRow:myRow inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is assuming I even know what you're looking for.  Did you just want to set the initial selection, or were you trying to figure out where to initialize the pickerView?

Comment: just setting the initial selection!  Will try your suggestion and see if it works and accept soon - thank you so much!

Comment: tried option #2 which unfortunately does not work for me. The picker  is still setting up its rows and components and throws an exception.  TO be more explicit, I have a 3 component picker that is loaded up with variables from an nsdisctionary, and the values in the 2nd component are dependent on what is in the first component, and the values in the third dependent on the first and second... SO I need to have the whole barrel picker loaded and ready to go before I can make a selection.  I thought there might be some easy "UIPicker finished loading" method that I could stick it in.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Try it after `[self.actionSheet addSubview:self.vintagePicker];`  In my code, I add the subView elsewhere, and then set the `selectRow:inComponent`.  I changed the code above to reflect this.

Comment: I tried - didn't work :o(  Think I might have to give up on this and stick it back into a ViewController that only goes up half the page like an action sheet just to get ViewDidLoad back again.  Have also tried a BOOL flag for showingFirstSelection and putting a method in pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent but it does not update the last component.  What a pain.